# Notification in javascript - similar to new emails in gmail

Tags: javascript

I am creating a widget which will update some live NEWS happening. I want to push notification to the widget everytime I get some new information in my  database.  It is similar to live feed.  I am unsure how to start this one in javascript.

I donot want to poll every nth second to get the information. I want the server to push information to the client everytime the server gets a new information.

It is similar to gmail. You get an email even without refreshing the page.

Any pointers will be definitely helpful.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Web sockets, WAMP pub/sub, AJAX requests, long polling... investigate those things.

Comment: http://ape-project.org/ https://www.igvita.com/2013/06/12/innovating-with-http-2.0-server-push/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: I am using C#/asp.net for the purpose. I want it simple and neat. Please dont make it complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by ajax requests. Can you please elaborate. I need a push technology. that is only when something happens it should trigger. I dont need a polling/pulling technology where it constantly polls every n seconds.

Comment: @Gael. It is an experimental technology and it doesnot work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 choices, what I can think of:

1. Using **HTTP**, you can ask the server every x second, if it has any new information, and if it does, then load & show it. If you are using HTTP, the server can't contact the client, it can only answer the clients requests.
2. Using **sockets**, you can create a 2 way communication, both the client can send data to the server, and the server can send data to the client. This way the server can send the information as soon, as possible. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) you can find information about the supported browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate Node server can help to separate the business logic from polling operations. 
Needs to install these packages - **socket.io, express, request**

```
npm install <package_names>
```

To get request data from node :

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
 socket.emit('pollNodeServer',JSON.stringify(requestToServer));
```

On server :

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request'),
    app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Server started at port 3000');

var options = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'User-Agent' : 'request'
    }
};
socket.on('pollNodeServer', function(data, callbackfn) {
    requestServer(data,socket,callbackfn);
});
```

Reply from server :

```
socket.emit('returnJobs',JSON.parse(body));
```